# PowerShell dir /ah not working?

Tags: powershell

When I try `dir /ah` under Windows 10 I get the following:

```
PS C:\Users\Robert\dev\fiedz> dir /ah
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\ah' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir /ah
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\ah:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: why did you add the tag `powershell-v2.0` - windows 10 has v5?

Comment: `dir -h` (see my comment on the other answer)

Comment: Any idea why? Yes, because that is how `Get-ChildItem` works, which has `dir` as an alias.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the dos command dir /ah, and not the Get-ChildItem alias:

```
cmd /c <command>
```

In your case:

```
cmd /c dir /ah
```

Answer (score 1):

Dir is only an alias to Get-ChildItem in PowerShell.
Since the path separator `/` is also accepted you got that error msg.
To resemble cmd dir behavior use the `-force` parameter

To select only files with a given Attribute check with a piped where:

```
Gci c:\ -force|Where Attributes -like '*Hidden*'
```

**Edit** Just remembered there also is a shortcut, you can use

```
ls c:\ -ah
```

Comment: That's a TON of work to the equivalent of the Unix ls -a or even the windows dir /ah

Comment: Edited my answer. In general there some small caveats with PowerShell but they are outweighted by the advantages.

Comment: You can `gci -h` as well, where the `-h` will tab complete to `-Hidden` if you need the full name, that's in PS v4 at least.

Comment: So the short answer to the original question is to use `dir -h` in PowerShell, which is the same as `Get-ChildItem -Hidden`.

Comment: dir -ah doesnt work, prints nothing. Missing my linux bash :(

Comment: There may be no files with the hidden attribute - use `-force` to show all

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
 Get-ChildItem -Hidden
```

Comment: When you need to type that much stuff to get a directory listing the shell is anti-productivity.

Comment: A complaint is not a question.